# Download folder of scripts from s3 with run command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I have a folder of scripts in S3.

There is a "main" script that is executed which depends on some other scripts in the folder.

I can run a single script from s3 like this:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunRemoteScript" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=instance-IDs" --parameters '{"sourceType":["S3"],"sourceInfo":["{\"path\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/path_to_script\"}"],"commandLine":["script_name_and_arguments"]}'
```

Can I have SSM download an entire folder and execute one script in the folder after it is downloaded?

Comment: It is probably easiest to have the Run Command execute a single script, and then that script could download the folder (using `aws s3 sync`) and call the main script in the folder.

Comment: my pain is windows. the crappy aws cmdelts dont have high level s3 commands. So I either have to roll a custom ami with awscli or recurse over all the objects in the PS script that copies them down

Comment: You should be able to install the AWS CLI via a User Data script, or as part of the Run Command script. Let us know if you have a problem with the installation.